# Calcular total puntos

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola necesitaria ayuda o alguna idea para como calcular el score total de este juego de cartas en JavaScript, el problema es que cada vez que llamo a la función puntuación me resetea las variables internas y no puedo crear la puntuación total

```
// Funcion puntuacion y calculos
function puntuacion(array) {


    var ultimaTirada = 0;
    var puntuacionTotal = 0;
    var valColor1 = 0;
    var valColor2 = 0;
    var valColor3 = 0;
    var valColor4 = 0;

    // Hacemos el calculo de que si el color que esta en esa posicion de la array es ese, que haga el caluclo correspondiente

    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){


                if (array[i] == 'red'){                    
                    valColor1 += -2 ;

                } else if(array[i] == 'green'){

                    valColor2 += 3;

                } else if(array[i] == 'blue'){

                    valColor3 += 2;

                } else if(array[i] == 'yellow'){

                    valColor4 += 1;
                }      

                 ultimaTirada = valColor1 + valColor2 + valColor3 + valColor4;


         }
         // Guardo la ultima tirada y voy sumando

        totalScore += ultimaTirada; // Aquí tengo el error // 

    // Pinto la ultima tirada y el total del score
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Valor de la ultima Tirada: <b>" + ultimaTirada + " </b><br>Puntuación Final: " + puntuacionTotal;

}

// Colores random 
/* Math.random() entre 5 color azul,rojo,verde,amarillo, 
El color rojo resta puntos*/
function coloresRandom() {

    // Ocultamos los bototnes de modos de juego
    if (document.getElementById("C2").style.visibility == 'visible'){
        document.getElementById("jugar3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("jugar4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("jugar5").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    // Variable para random
    var numRandom;

    // Blue
    // Red
    // Green
    // Yellow
    var arrayColores = ["url('http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jUiUFYNSktQ/Vi-KImE5GnI/AAAAAAAErfM/8n2P2wH_sug/s1600/FONDOS%2BPARA%2BTEL%25C3%2589FONOS%2B%252843%2529.gif')",
                        "url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QUpi_xZM79o/Vi-KI9pd8ZI/AAAAAAAErfQ/eS4pxUlJu4Q/s1600/FONDOS%2BPARA%2BTEL%25C3%2589FONOS%2B%252844%2529.gif')", 
                        "url('https://k36.kn3.net/3/1/4/4/7/8/23F.gif')",
                        "url('https://k36.kn3.net/9/F/8/9/6/2/B26.gif')"];

    var colores = ['','','',''];
    // id name
    var carta1 = document.getElementById("C1");
    var carta2 = document.getElementById("C2");
    var carta3 = document.getElementById("C3");
    var carta4 = document.getElementById("C4");
    var carta5 = document.getElementById("C5");

    // Contador
    var contador = 0;
    // Miramos si es visible , si lo es la contamos 

    if (carta1.style.visibility == 'visible' && carta2.style.visibility == 'visible' && carta3.style.visibility == 'visible' && carta4.style.visibility == 'visible' && carta5.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        contador = 5;
    }else if (carta1.style.visibility == 'visible' && carta2.style.visibility == 'visible' && carta3.style.visibility == 'visible' && carta4.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        contador = 4;

    } else if (carta2.style.visibility == 'visible' && carta3.style.visibility == 'visible' && carta4.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        contador = 3;

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < contador; i++) {        
        numRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() *4));
        // Guardar en cada numero un color
        if(numRandom == 0){
            colores[i] = 'red';
        } else if(numRandom == 1){
            colores[i] = 'green';
        } else if(numRandom == 2){
            colores[i] = 'blue';
        } else if(numRandom == 3){
            colores[i] = 'yellow';
        }

        if (i == 3) {       
            carta1.style.backgroundImage = arrayColores[numRandom];

        } else if (i == 0) {
            carta2.style.backgroundImage = arrayColores[numRandom];

        } else if (i == 1) {
            carta3.style.backgroundImage = arrayColores[numRandom];

        } else if (i == 2) {
            carta4.style.backgroundImage = arrayColores[numRandom];

        } else if (i == 4) {
            carta5.style.backgroundImage = arrayColores[numRandom];
        }


    }

    puntuacion(colores);    

}
```

[image: Este es el problema que tengo]

Comment: por favor trata de colocar menos codigo y agregas el error en particular

Comment: Creo que esta mejor explicado ahora

Comment: porque no colocas la variable puntuacionTotal fuera de la funcion y aplicas la suma?, asi evitas que se reinicie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var total = 0;
// Función para mostrar por pantalla el resultado tanto de la ultima tirada como el total
function puntuacionTotal(){
    // Invocamos la puntuacion de la ultima tirada y la guardamos en una variable
    var ultima = puntuacion(coloresRandom());
    // hacemos la suma
    total = ultima + total;
    // Lo mostranmos
    document.getElementById("puntos").innerHTML = "Ultima Tirada: " + ultima + 
        "
Total: " + total;
}
```

Comment: Como cierro el tema?

Comment: Hola Eduard. Para que sea una respuesta válida has de explicar cómo funciona. Es mejor ponerlo fuera del codigo en vez de como comentarios. Mira [answer] para más info. Para "cerrar el tema" pulsa en el icono del check a la izq, donde la puntuacion de la respuesta, para marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en lo que se conoce el ámbito de la función, más específicamente estás inicializando las variables en la función puntuación por lo que cada vez que la llama se inicializa de nuevo. Una forma de resolver esto es usar variables globales.

Ejemplo:

```js
// Inicializar

var puntuacionTotal = 0;
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click',puntuacion);

// Funciones
function puntuacion(){
  puntuacionTotal += 1; 
  console.info(puntuacionTotal);
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Suma 1">
```

Comment: Gracias pero eso aun no se aplicarlo

Comment: @Eduard ¿Viste el ejemplo que incluí? ¿Algo no está claro del mismo?

Comment: Si lo he visto pero no se aplicar el querySelector , addEventListener , console.info. Pero ya esta solucionado

Comment: @EduardNastrut que bueno que ya quedó solucionado. Si mi respuesta te ayudó podrías aceptarla si no fue así, publica tu solución como respuesta.

Comment: Esta es mi solución                                                                           
 var total = 0;
// Función para mostrar por pantalla el resultado tanto de la ultima tirada como el total
function puntuacionTotal(){
    // Invocamos la puntuacion de la ultima tirada y la guardamos en una variable
    var ultima = puntuacion(coloresRandom());
    // hacemos la suma
    total = ultima + total;
    // Lo mostranmos
    document.getElementById("puntos").innerHTML = "Ultima Tirada: " + ultima + 
        "<br>Total: " + total;
}

Comment: @EduardNastrut Publícala como respuesta. Los comentarios sólo son para solicitar aclaraciones o dar sugerencias de cómo mejorar las preguntas/respuestas.